# setting an object reference to null

Tags: c#

```
var list1 = new List<obj>();
var list2 = new List<obj>();
var item = new obj();
list1.Add(item);
list1.Add(item);
```

is there a way in c# to set all references in the current application to null if one reference that has the same reference value got set to null?

for example when i do `list[0]=null or item=null`, i want to set any reference in the current application that holds the same reference value to null so that the GC handles them, at the same time i dont want this behaviour for all Types, is there such thing in c#?

to get the idea
if i say

```
 list1[0] = null
```

i want it at the same time to mean

```
list2[0] = null;
item = null;
```

Comment: "No". However, for some specific situations, [Weak References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247(v=vs.110).aspx) are a viable approach.

Comment: you loop the list and check if any value is null then make other values to be replaces with the null value

Comment: @kumarch1 its not about lists, the reference can be anywhere in the app

Comment: WeakReferences are not required, just their usage pattern. Ie route all access through 1 intermediate reference.

Comment: It's definitely not built into .Net, but it sounds like the observer pattern might be useful here, if I'm following you correctly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: @user1492051: No there is nothing built-in because you do not need this and shouldn't be wanting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce an additional layer of indirection in your memory references. The simplest way would be to create a `Nullable<T>` type for classes:

```
public class Nullable<T> where T : class
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Nullable(T initial)
    {
        this.Value = initial;
    }
}
```

You could then use this type to wrap your objects:

```
var list1 = new List<Nullable<object>>();
var list2 = new List<Nullable<object>>();
var item = new Nullable<object>(new object());
list1.Add(item);
list2.Add(item);
item.Value = null;    // clears value from all collections
```

Comment: That is a nice workaround without the need to create extra classes

Comment: i think thats a great solution, there is only one type that i need to have this behaviour, will test it

Comment: The name is a dangerous choice, [see Nullable<T> on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This might work under very limited conditions but wreaks havoc on everything needing Equality.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The name choice was intentional; the class serves a similar purpose to the built-in struct. And equality can easily be accounted for through a proper implementation (starting with `IEquatable<T>`).

Comment: but still when you set it to item.Value null we still have a reference to a Nullable<obj> except its Value property is null, which i think is not that bad but i will still have references to the Nullable itself, but its a good solution still, can you think of a workaround for this?

Comment: @user1492051: The references stored in your lists or variables are essentially memory addresses. At code level, references that point to the same object have no relation to each other; they just happen to store the same address. By using `Nullable<T>`, we [reified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)) the notion of references to give us another level of indirection (and, thereby, explicit control over the references' values). Without that, you'd need to alter the CLR to get the behaviour you're requesting.

Comment: whoever the CLR is haha, i didn't have the chance to meet her, pretty satisfied with this solution though ;)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to automatically set other variables to null, but if your point is to get the object garbage collected even though you still have other references to it, you can do that.

You need to use weak references. Weak references are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: WeakReferences are not required. And the only good advice is: don't do it.